# Cocos2d animation resume

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase, freeze

I've added iAP in cocos2d following the ray tutorials (but changed a few things to fit cocos2d) but after I make a transaction the console log says `2013-08-19 16:32:12.626 Game[2483:907] Buying *product* ...
2013-08-19 16:32:13.208 Game[2483:907] cocos2d: animation stopped
2013-08-19 16:32:16.690 Game[2483:907] completeTransaction...
2013-08-19 16:32:16.725 Game[2483:907] User defaults for *product* are YES`

So I know the transaction works, but the game never resumes it just freezes. Is there a way to resume the game after the transaction? `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]resume]` doesn't work so I think it may have to do with UIAlert View. Any help? Here is my iAPHelper.mm:

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification
@"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

@implementation IAPHelper {

SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;

RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;
NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;

}

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }

}
return self;
}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

_completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
}

_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
_productsRequest = nil;

_completionHandler(NO, nil);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
};
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
}

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

[_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];
NSLog(@"User defaults for %@ are YES", productIdentifier);
}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you popup your alert view try running...

```
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
```

When you get a response back from the user in the alertview callback or transaction completion run...

```
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
```

Cocos doesn't often play well with UIKit/Cocoa callbacks so you need to pause rendering while they do their thing.  We have similar behaviour for when the app goes into background/foreground in the app delegate...

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

Seems we use resume inside the applicationDidBecomeActive.  Can't recall the full logic there but that has seemed to work for a bunch of our projects.